# How to change font size for GTK menus, autocomplete, properties view and pop-up hints in Eclipse Neon?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon

I need to change eclipse menu size.
also in properties view. 
high resolution makes the font so tiny.
I found a way to change package explorer view font size by modifying an eclipse related file in css folder.

eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.1.1.v20151026-1355\css

but how to change "IDE menu" font size in eclipse?
also how to change "Properties view" or auto complete (control+space menu) font size in eclipse?
I searched every where for an answer for this question.

Comment: Did you try eclipse neon? This problem is resolved in neon

Comment: @Sraven - I just installed neon; can you please help me where is the option? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, my Eclipse uses GTK so I tried to change the font size via the Kubuntu system settings and it worked. It applies also to pop-up hints in Eclipse. 
[image: KDE GTK settings in Kubuntu (czech)]